# Complex map exercise

Tags: complex-numbers

> Give a discusion of the mapping $f(z)= \frac{1}{2}(z+1/z)$

This is a exercise from functions of one complex variable.

The problem is that I guess I have to draw it or show the propierties about it, I saw its derivate but I don't find anything helpful.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $z=a+bi$. Then you surely know that $\bar{z}=a-bi$.
Moreover $z\cdot\bar{z}=|z|^2=a^2+b^2$.
Thus $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{\bar{z}}{|z|^2}$.
And therefore $2 f(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}=a+bi+\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}=a\frac{a^2+b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}+b\frac{a^2+b^2-1}{a^2+b^2}i$.
Or stated differently: $2 f(z)=Re(z)\frac{|z|^2+1}{|z|^2}+Im(z)\frac{|z|^2-1}{|z|^2}i$.

--- rk

Answer (score 0):

May be your function was slightly wrong and you meant $g(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\bar{z}^{-1})$ instead.

Then a way to address this discussion, would be to observe that $\bar{z}^{-1}$ is nothing but the image of the point $z$, when inverted at the circle of unity.

Thus the function $g(z)$ provides for any point $z\in\mathbb{C}^*$ the medium between the according image and pre-image.

--- rk

Comment: No, the function has 1/2 but thanks.

Comment: oops, forgot that 1/2 (now corrected above). - Whereas my actual change was taking the complex conjugation to the inverse as well. Then both numbers lie on the same ray from the origin!